# MQTT:How to know when user disconnect

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am using mqtt protocol for chat. So i have a requirement in my project to send push notification to subscriber when subscriber disconnected. I searched a lot about how can i get to know when subscriber or any person leave room chat. i read about last will message,but it will be delivered by broker when any user disconnected unexpectedly or application close.

Is there any flag or point where i can know when user simply disconnect itself.

I am using mosquitto broker.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

Only the application that manages connections will know when users connect/disconnect/send messages etc..

You should be able to handle all of that logic in a separate place from the message broker/ messaging protocol.